How to pass an "argumentized" scriptblock to pwsh that wrapped within Start-Process?
pwsh -command $([scriptblock]::Create('param($p1,$p2) write-host $p1 $p2; write-host ''hello'' $p2; pause;')) -args 'hi', 'world' -NoExit

prints and complies with -NoExit
hi world
hello world
Press Enter to continue...

However when launched by Start-Process
Start-Process -FilePath "pwsh" -Wait -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList @("-command",$([scriptblock]::Create('param($p1,$p2) write-host $p1 $p2; write-host ''hello'' $p2; pause;')), '-args', 'hi', 'world', '-NoExit')

prints and exits immediately (simply ignores -NoExit).

hello
Press Enter to continue... :
-args: The term 'args' is not regcogized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.


What's the best practice to pass an "argumentized" `scriptblock` pwsh (like below) into `Start-Process` ?
pwsh -command { param($p1,$p2) write-host $p1 $p2; write-host 'hello' $p2; pause; } -args 'hi', 'world' -NoExit


That depends a bit on what you mean by "argumentized" - will you be passing user-defined arguments to the scriptblock in the new process, or do you control both the scriptblock and the argument values?

Why use start-process?

@MathiasR.Jessen My use case two arguments are simple url and filename string, that's all. And yes, I control both side of callings. Well, it seems the infamous stringified  scriptblocks are here to stay unfortunately.

@js2010 It's just because I don't know another way to spawn other pwsh tab on my windows terminal. Any methods are very welcome.

@sandthorn, re opening a Windows Terminal tab: you can do that via a call to wt.exe - please see the bottom section of my answer.



Passing a script block containing statements to execute to pwsh, the PowerShell (Core) 7 CLI (the same applies to powershell.exe, the legacy Windows PowerShell CLI) is only meaningfully supported in direct invocation, not also via Start-Process, and also not when calling the PowerShell CLI from outside a PowerShell session.

It is only in this invocation form (which typically uses { ... }, i.e. a script-block literal) that (a) an -args parameter is supported, to pass pass-through arguments as an array and (b) -NoExit is not required to precede -Command (see next point).


-NoExit isn't being honored in your Start-Process call, because in a non-script-block-based invocation - which a Start-Process call invariably is, whether or not you pass an actual script block (which simply gets stringified) - anything that follows the
-Command CLI parameter is considered a pass-through argument, i.e. a part of the argument(s) that (potentially together) form the code passed to -Command.


Therefore, your Start-Process command should be:
Start-Process -FilePath pwsh -Wait -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList @'
  -NoExit -Command "& { param($p1,$p2) write-host $p1 $p2; write-host 'hello' $p2; pause }" 'hi' 'world'
'@

Note:

A verbatim here-string is used to make embedded quoting easier.

The commands to execute are - of necessity - passed as a string, enclosed in "..." overall.

So as to allow the commands to act like a script [block] that can accept arguments, they are enclosed in { ... } inside the string, i.e. the target PowerShell instance constructs a script block from them.

The resulting script block must then be invoked, using &, the call operator.

These somewhat awkward requirements would be obviated if -Command treated its first argument implicitly like a script block and all subsequent ones as arguments to pass to that block.

The experimental PSCommandWithArgs feature (as of PowerShell 7.4.x) introduces a -CommandWithArgs parameter that implements this behavior. As with any experimental feature, (a) it must be enabled in order to be available and (b) there's no guarantee that the feature will become a stable one.
# PowerShell 7.4+ only
# Only works if the following was run in a PREVIOUS session:
#   Enable-ExperimentalFeature PSCommandWithArgs
Start-Process -FilePath pwsh -Wait -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList @'
  -NoExit -CommandWithArgs "param($p1,$p2) write-host $p1 $p2; write-host 'hello' $p2; pause" "hi" "world"
'@ 


Note the absence of the & { ... } enclosure and how the pass-through arguments are now "..."-enclosed, because they are now no longer parsed as PowerShell code (as they are with -Command, see below), but as literal arguments that support double-quoting only (though in this case, given that the arguments contain no spaces, quoting can be omitted altogether).






Note that if the commands were to contain " themselves, such " instances would have to be escaped as \".

As for quoting the pass-through arguments:

While enclosing them in '...' works in principle, note that if they were to contain runs of two or more spaces, you'd have to pass them enclosed in "'...'" (sic), so as to avoid whitespace normalization; the enclosing " characters are removed by PowerShell during the initial command-line parsing.

Note that PowerShell uses two passes to parse the arguments that follow -Command: first, unescaped " characters are removed, and second, the resulting arguments are joined with spaces to form a string that is then interpreted as PowerShell source code - see this answer for details.


Alternatively, given the above, include the pass-through arguments inside the "..." string enclosing the commands, i.e. pass both the commands and the arguments to pass to them as a single, "..."-enclosed -Command argument.





Opening a new Windows Terminal tab in which to run a given PowerShell CLI call:

In a comment you state that the reason for using Start-Process - which is typically not necessary in this scenario, see this answer - is to run the command in a new Windows terminal tab (which only works if Windows Terminal is the default terminal on your system, which is true out of the box, nowadays).

However, it is simpler to pass a PowerShell CLI command line to wt.exe, the Windows Terminal CLI, as shown below.

With the exception of having to escape ; characters as \; even inside "...",[1] the PowerShell command line can be passed as in direct, string-based invocation - in essence, pwsh followed by the content of the -ArgumentList argument above.



# Note the unexpected need to \-escape ; characters.
wt pwsh -NoExit -Command '& { param($p1,$p2) write-host $p1 $p2\; write-host ''hello'' $p2\; pause }' hi there

Note:

From a PowerShell session, the script block-based syntax works too, but that should be considered a bug - see GitHub issue #5187 - and it is therefore better not to rely on it.
# Arguably SHOULDN'T work, because pwsh isn't invoked *directly*,
# but still does as of PowerShell 7.4
wt pwsh -NoExit -Command { param($p1,$p2) write-host $p1 $p2; write-host 'hello' $p2; pause } -Args 'hi', 'there'




[1] Even though the command shown later uses '...' quoting, PowerShell - of necessity - translates that to "...", i.e. double-quoting behind the scenes, when it constructs the process command line to execute, given that CLIs can only be expected to understand double-quoting.
To wt.exe, ; is a metacharacter, i.e. a character with special meaning (it separates multiple commands that each create a new tab/window or split pane) and therefore requires escaping as \; in order to be used verbatim.
The surprising aspect is that it also treats an unescaped ; as a metacharacter inside "...", so that, in effect, all pass-through ; instances must be escaped as \;.
GitHub docs issue #763 suggested amending the docs accordingly; while a PR was submitted in response, it didn't actually address the issue.

Have you tried the new -CommandWithArgs  approach? If it works in this case, please also add that to your already superb answer. Kudos.

Thanks, @sandthorn. Good idea re demonstrating -CommandWithArgs use - please see my update.

@sandthorn, I think the answer now fully addresses your question - let us know if you think something is missing.

I found that "` and '` are inconsistant in -Command and -CommandWithArgs. Only u{0027} and u{0022} express well in both. I'm not sure is that a bug. (Well, obviously it is ...here in the markdown.)

@sandthorn, no, that's not a bug, and the reason is explained in the answer: with -Command, all arguments following -Command are - after removal of unescaped " characters during the initial command-line parsing - subject to interpretation as PowerShell code (where '...' strings are recognized even when calling from outside PowerShell); by contrast, with -CommandWithArgs, this interpretation by design only applies to the first subsequent argument.
